# "And" condition in C#/LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

```
partial void PrintDocLetter1_CanExecute(ref bool result)
    {
        if (this.PatientsMasterItem.DoctorsMasterItem != null)
        {

            var Doctor = PatientsMasterItem.DoctorsMasterItem;

            var PatientList = Doctor.PatientsMasterItem;

            var Letters = PatientsMasterItem.LettersSentItem;

            if ((PatientList.Count() > 1) && (Letters.Any(i => i.LetterType == "DoctorLetter1")))
            {
                result = false;
            }
            else
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }


    }
```

I think something is wrong with my second condition. I'm trying to find two things.
1) Doctors with more than 1 patient.
2) Among those patients whether a lettertype called "DoctorLetter1" has been sent or not.

The above code is working good for that particular record but not working other patients with same doctors where patient1 has already been sent with DoctorLetter1.

Comment: try joining patientlist with letters then apply the query

Comment: Shoaib I'm new to C# and LINQ. Can you show me how to do a join in the above case ?

Comment: what are the columns in Patient and Letter entity. what relationship they have? is it on patientid?

Comment: Please find the ER diagram. Sorry for not providing enough details.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/i4laP.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this condition

```
(Letters.Any(i => i.LetterType == "DoctorLetter1")
```

### updated (as per your ER diagram)

you didn't check all Patients 's Letter. try..

```
if(Doctor.PatientsMasterItem.Count > 1 
&& Doctor.PatientsMasterItem.Any(patient => 
  patient.LettersSentItem.Any(letter => letter.LetterType == "DoctorLetter1")))
{
  result = false;
}
```

*logic

Doctor has many patients and each patient has many letters.

if any patient (only one of them) has at least one "DoctorLetter1" sent then condition is true and **result = false**

Comment: `Error 1 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.EntityCollection<LightSwitchApplication.PatientsMasterItem>' does not contain a definition for 'LettersSentItem' and no extension method 'LettersSentItem' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Framework.EntityCollection<LightSwitchApplication.PatientsMasterItem>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

please find ER diagram here http://i.stack.imgur.com/i4laP.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to implement same in the following case this time I was just checking for data entry errors. The problem in this case is when same doctor has multiple addresses the validation fails. The record is being treated as on even though I added unique index for firstname,lastname and hospital in doctors table.

Comment: `partial void DoctorsMasterItem_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)

        {

            if (this.DoctorsMasterItem != null)

            {

                var HospName = this.HospitalName;
                var DoctorHospital = this.DoctorsMasterItem.HospitalName;


                if (HospName != DoctorHospital)


                {


                    results.AddPropertyError("Make Sure the Hospital Patient belongs to and Doctor is also part of that hospital else your letters address would be wrong");

                   
                }

            }

        }`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
PatientList.Count(c=>c.Letters.Any(i => i.LetterType == "DoctorLetter1")) > 1
```

Hope there is a relationship between Patient and Letter.